# D3.js .selectAll not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Working through this 
http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/

In this line of code:

```
var node = nodesG.selectAll("circle.node").data(nodes, function (d) {
        console.log("hello");
        return d.id;
    });
```

the `console.log` is never run. I'm not sure why.

This is `nodesG`:

```
var vis = d3.select(selection).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
nodesG = vis.append("g").attr("id", "nodes");
```

Comment: Is the g element appearing in the dom?

Answer (score 2):

2 things come to mind. Either the parent does not exist, or the data is empty.
Either that, or this part of the code is never reached.

Try this:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5]

var body = d3.select("body")
var nothing = d3.select("#wut")

//shouldn't be called
var noparent = nothing.selectAll("div").data(data, function(d){
    alert("no parent CALLED"); return d;
})

var nodata = body.selectAll("div").data([], function(d){
    alert("no data CALLED"); 
    return d;
})

var wrongdata = body.selectAll("div").data({banana:2, apple:3}, function(d){
    alert("wrong data CALLED"); 
    return d;
})

//should be called
var noenter = body.selectAll("div").data(data, function(d){
    alert("no enter CALLED"); 
    return d;
})

var nodes = body.selectAll("div").data(data, function(d){
    alert("normal CALLED"); 
    return d;
}).enter().append("div")
  .text(function(d){ return d})
```

Edit: I added the test which shows that a non-array won't cause a join.

Comment: so the problem was that data was not being passed an array.

Comment: er no- the data was not empty, it just wasn't an array.

Comment: OK. I added that test as well.